# Understanding Volume Bars Threshold

Tags: time-series, market-data, tick-data, volume

I have been reading *Advances in Financial Machine Learning* by *Marcos López de Prado* and came across different Bar types, and simulating **Volume Bars** from execution data myself.

My understanding of **Volume Bars** is that they are based on a **given number of shares traded (volume)**. Each bar represents trades whose **total volume is equal to the volume threshold**. A new bar is created when the total volume of the current bar reaches the threshold.

But the output of existing libraries[*1] based on the said book contradicts my understanding.
What am I missing here?

---

To be more specific...

... Suppose we have below raw trade data, and set **the threshold to 5**.

[image]

I expect the Volume Bars to be like the following ...

[image]

The libraries return the Volume Bars like this...

[image]

[*1]
[mlfinlab by Hudson and Thames](https://github.com/hudson-and-thames/mlfinlab/blob/318bc9f0bbff5b7d55ea7e08578ab57cd6d3dc09/mlfinlab/data_structures/standard_data_structures.py#L91)
[Adv_Fin_ML_Exercises by BlackArbsCEO](https://github.com/BlackArbsCEO/Adv_Fin_ML_Exercises/blob/master/notebooks/Tick%2C%20Volume%2C%20Dollar%20Volume%20Bars.ipynb)

Answer (score 1):

The logic used by the library is to combine all trades equal or above the threshold and to never split one trade over two bars. So 6 becomes its own bar and 2 and 7 combine to be one bar.

I think this makes more sense than your approach. In the second table you show two bars with the same time. When using time on the x-axis there is no good way to even plot that as the bars will overlap.